# Pourquoi « enquerre » est-il un verbe ?

Tags: grammaire, ancien-français

Le mot « enquerre » est un verbe qui ne s'emploie qu'à l'infinitif. Par exemple, on parle d'« armes à enquerre » ou encore on met « un mot à l'enquerre ». Ma question est donc : pourquoi ce mot qui s'emploie dans de telles expressions est-il un verbe ?

Comment: Tu pars sur un faux *a priori*. Où as-tu vu/lu que ce mot ne s'employait (son usage est à mettre plutôt à l'imparfait) que comme verbe ?

Comment: @Laure « L'Officiel du Scrabble », le dictionnaire de référence du jeu de Scrabble francophone de compétition, n'indique que « v. déf. » (verbe défectif) à l'entrée « enquerre ».

Comment: Ce n'est pas une source scientifique. il y a des sources plus fiables pour ce qui est de l'usage et de l'étymologie. Déjà commence par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/)

Comment: @Laure Merci, je saurai pour la prochaine fois. Ceci étant dit, le mot « enquerre » est peut-être aussi un substantif, mais il n'en reste pas moins que c'est aussi un verbe, ce qui est toujours surprenant à mon avis.

Comment: Ça n'est surprenant que dans la langue actuelle, or le mot n'est plus utilisé depuis des milliers d'années. En ancien français ce n'était pas plus surprenant qu'autre chose. Emploi du verbe en contexte  *...à la requeste de Jehan Belepite le jeune, pour savoir et enquerre à savoir mon  se  l'usage et la coustume est tele as marès de Carentan, que toutes foiz que la mer sousprent...*. [En contexte](http://www.wikimanche.fr/Coutume_des_marais_de_Carentan_%281324%29).

Comment: @Laure Vous avez raison. Un exemple bien choisi permet de tout éclaircir ! Je vous remercie.

Comment: Personne n'a remarqué mon énorme bourde sur les ordres de grandeur ! Dans mon commentaire précédents j'ai mis un zéro de trop.. je voulais dire centaines et non pas milliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Enquerre » vient du latin *inquiere*  (rechercher, interroger, faire une enquête). Il a donné le verbe « enquérir » apparu au 13<sup>e</sup> siècle.

En ancien français le mot existait comme nom et comme verbe, à une époque où les formes verbales n'étaient pas encore fixées et les terminaisons des infinitifs différentes de notre classement actuel.

Déjà en 1762 le *[Dictionnaire de l'Académie françoise](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k504034)* signale terme comme vieux et n'ayant plus d'usage que dans le blason. Et il est signalé comme n'étant plus employé que comme substantif. 
« Un mot à l'enquerre » (ne se dit plus de nos jours) était un mot dont on recherchait l'étymologie.

*Enquerre* comme verbe et comme nom a disparu complètement de l'usage courant au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle et ne s'emploie plus en français actuel que comme nom dans l'expression du vocabulaire de l'héraldique : « armes à enquerre » (on rencontre aussi parfois  « armes *enquerrées* » ou *enquérantes*) pour dire que ces armes présentent une anomalie et qu'elles sont soumises à vérification.

Sources : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (Ed. Le Robert, sld Alain Rey) et  *Dictionnaire de l'Académie françoise*, ed. 1762.